# Button that appends data to a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to create an excel workbook, where I will have a button(s) - when clicked on it, it should write the date, number of times it clicked on that day.

I am able to write the date, based on a macro, however I am struggling in two scenarios. Presently I am only able to update the date in the same cell. 
 1. I would like to append it, in the row below, rather erase the same cell and update it. 
 2. The number of times the user clicked on the day (should be on the column next to it), should be updated dynamically, and should match the date column next to it.

Any thoughts on the logic, would be helpful.

This is the result, I am looking to get, this is two columns.

```
7/29/19     5
7/30/19     9
7/31/19     12
```

Comment: I would like to make sure I understand your question. So when this button is clicked, if it's a NEW date, then it will add the current date to the next row and start a new counter. If the current date matches the most recent one on the list when the button is pressed, then it will simply add +1 to the count for that day.

Comment: Tom - You got it right. Just one thing - the next row, should be at the end of the column (to make sure we are on the same page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to start, we're going to have to have our program figure out what cell contains the most recent date that is in our list. Once we get that cell, we can compare it's value to the current date in order to determine if we need to add +1 to that day or start a new row.

I have provided an example subroutine below and you will have to replace the contents inside of the square brackets to match your sheet that you're working in.

```
Sub buttonPressed()
    Dim lastRow, dateColumn As Long
    Dim lastDate As Date
    Dim clickCtr As Long

    With Sheets([sheetName])
        'Set the column containing dates.
        dateColumn = [column number where dates are stored]

        'Get the last row containing a date and save it into lastRow
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, dateColumn).End(xlUp).row

        'Convert value of lastRow into a date
        lastDate = DateValue(.Cells(lastRow, dateColumn).Value)

        'Compare last date to current date
        If (lastDate = Date) Then
            'Get the current button press count and add 1 to it
            clickCtr = .Cells(lastRow, dateColumn + 1).Value + 1
            'Replace contents of cell with new click amount
            .Cells(lastRow, dateColumn + 1).Value = clickCtr
        Else
            'Add the new date to the next row
            .Cells(lastRow + 1, dateColumn).Value = Date
            'Start the counter next to the new date
            .Cells(lastRow + 1, dateColumn + 1).Value = 1
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking here's my attempt at it.

```
Sub stuff()
    Dim dateCol As Range
    Dim countCol As Range

    Set dateCol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A") ' Change to proper sheet
    Set countCol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B") ' Change to proper sheet

    Dim foundDate As Range
    Dim searchDate As String
    searchDate = Format(Now(), "m/dd/yyyy")
    Set foundDate = dateCol.Find(what:=searchDate, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not foundDate Is Nothing Then
        foundDate.Offset(0, 1).Value = foundDate.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
    Else
        Dim newEntry As Range
        If dateCol.Cells(1, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Set newEntry = dateCol.Cells(dateCol.Cells.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Else
            Set newEntry = dateCol.Cells(1, 1)
        End If
        newEntry.Value = searchDate
        newEntry.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
    End If

End Sub
```